# Error al insertar los datos de una tabla a otra con un valor autoincrementable(id) - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Al terminar de crear y salvar la base de datos me da un error. Estoy usando postgres4 en ubuntu. Este es el código que tengo puesto:

```
DECLARE
ultimo_id bigint:= lastval();
nnombre character varying:=(select nombre from registro r where r.id=ultimo_id);
napellidos character varying:=(select apellidos from registro r where r.id=ultimo_id);
nci bigint:=(select ci from registro r where r.id=ultimo_id);
nmotivo character varying:=(select motivo from registro r where r.id=ultimo_id);
ndepartamento character varying:=(select departamento from registro r where r.id=ultimo_id);
ntrabajador integer:=(select trabajador from registro r where r.id=ultimo_id);
nfecha date:=(select fecha from registro r where r.id=ultimo_id);
BEGIN
insert into traza(nombre, apellidos, ci, motivo, departamento, trabajador, fecha)
values(nnombre, napellidos, nci, nmotivo, ndepartamento, ntrabajador, nfecha);
END
```

Y aquí el tipo de error que obtengo:

> ERROR:  la ejecución alcanzó el fin del procedimiento disparador sin
> encontrar RETURN CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL add_registro2()

Gracias y saludos a la comunidad.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Porque haces todo esto en lugar de un INSERT INTO tabla SELECT * FROM origen where condiciones?

Comment: gracias trabajaré en su respuesta

Comment: BEGIN
INSERT INTO traza SELECT* FROM registro r;
END.                                                                                                                                                      Me continua dando error

Comment: yaaa resolví, gracias por la solución, pero tenía que devolver un **return null** al final de todo.